# Heroku ruby production error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I just had this error occurred in production and I was wondering does this have to do with heroku setup or my app?

This is the error :

```
ArgumentError: invalid %-encoding (\k9Λ|�x� ��(%0I0�Z���-g�뒨ڼ)
vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:898:in decode_www_form_component
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:41:in unescape
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:94:in block (2 levels) in parse_nested_query
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:94:in map
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:94:in block in parse_nested_query
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:93:in each
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:93:in parse_nested_query
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/request.rb:332:in parse_query
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:275:in parse_query
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/request.rb:209:in POST
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:237:in POST
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:10:in parameters
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/http/filter_parameters.rb:31:in filtered_parameters
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.2.96/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:37:in process_action
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in process
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in process
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in dispatch
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in dispatch
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in block in action
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in dispatch
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in block in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in each
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in call!
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:49:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.2.96/lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:12:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.2.96/lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:18:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.2.96/lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:16:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/request_store-1.0.5/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/client_side_validations-3.2.5/lib/client_side_validations/middleware.rb:21:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in context
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in block in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in run_1231007684488043729__call__3041923490950210072__callbacks
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in __run_callback
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in run_call_callbacks
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in run_callbacks
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in call_app
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in block in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in tagged
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in forward
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in fetch
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in lookup
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in call!
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/application.rb:231:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in methodmissing
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:64:in block in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in each
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/deflater.rb:13:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-rewrite-1.3.3/lib/rack/rewrite.rb:20:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:552:in process_client
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:632:in worker_loop
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.2.96/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/unicorn_instrumentation.rb:22:in call
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.2.96/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/unicorn_instrumentation.rb:22:in block (4 levels) in 
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in spawn_missing_workers
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:511:in maintain_worker_count
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:277:in join
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in 
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in load
from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in
```

Has anyone seen this kind of error before?

**Edit**

I just got 10th exception like this in prod, any suggestion how should I proceed?